# Meaning of do-while in this code

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, nextpeer

In the [tutorial of Nextpeer](https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/How+to+Make+a+Game+Like+Fun+Run+using+Nextpeer) you can see such code:

```
CCScene* GameLayer::scene() {
    CCScene * scene = NULL;
    do {
        // 'scene' is an autorelease object
        scene = CCScene::create();
        CC_BREAK_IF(! scene);

        // 'layer' is an autorelease object
        GameLayer *layer = GameLayer::create();
        CC_BREAK_IF(! layer);

        // add layer as a child to scene
        scene->addChild(layer);
    } while (0);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

What is the meaning of `do-while` block in this code?

Comment: It's there so you can execute the loop at most once while keeping a single return statement and without using `goto`. Especially in this function, screw the loop and just use `return`.

Comment: I'm curious what the definition of `CC_BREAK_IF` is. If it is literally just `#define CC_BREAK_IF(x) if (x) break;` then someone needs to be hit with the clue-by-four.

Comment: @cdhowie This is a first. A macro that is *longer* than the code it produces. Brilliant.

Comment: @Barry Indeed, all it really does is put the action before the conditional, presumably out of some misguided notion that it reads better. Similar to the Perl construct `x if y;` but at least there it's *part of the language* and therefore expected.

Comment: I think the macro can be defended since it's one of a collection of similar macros for error handling.  I've seen this pattern of error handling used in other projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CC_BREAK_IF` is a macro for `if(condition) break`. *(Edit: I've confirmed that [it is](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/a7cdc3e0fe2c389c9b85e07f1929eb655f0fbfc2/cocos/platform/CCPlatformMacros.h#L208).)*

This is an idiom used for a structured goto:

```
do {
    if (!condition0) break;
    action0();
    if (!condition1) break;
    action1();
} while(0);
```

`do...while(0);` exists only to allow a break statement to skip some section of code.

This would be similar to:

```
if (!condition0) goto end;
action0();
if (!condition1) goto end;
action1();
end:
```

Except it avoids the use of goto.

The use of either of these idioms is to avoid a nested `if`:

```
if (condition0) {
    action0();
    if (condition1) {
        action1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ the `break` statement works only in select contexts: a `while`, `do`/`while` or `for` loop or in a `switch` statement.  The `CC_BREAK_IF` macro presumably executes a `break` if the condition is met.  This is a simple method for handling exceptional/error conditions in C (a poor man's exception handling, if you will).

The `do`/`while` loop that never loops simply provides a context for the `break` statements to work.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is to make `CC_BREAK_IF` statements work correctly, that is to break the loop and jump to `return scene;`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common method when you have several conditional statements which would otherwise result in a chain of `if`/`else` clauses. Instead you use a single iteration loop and use `break` statements to exit the loop (`CC_BREAK_IF` is probably a macro which tests an expression and `break` if true).